# Whatsapp share button integration for browser websites

Tags: button, web, this, share, whatsapp

I am trying to integrate the Whatsapp share button on my website. But I found that WhatsApp works for mobile devices, not for the browser. So, is there any way to achieve the WhatsApp integration for websites.

Here is the Html link I am using:

`<a class="mct_whatsapp_btn" data-link="" data-text="" href="whatsapp://send?text=">Share</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I think it might help you.

`<a target="_blank" href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=www.google.com" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp web</a>`

This will open whatsapp web in the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<a href="https://wa.me/send?text=sample+message">Share via Whatsapp web</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this widget it's shows chat bubble icon on website where user can send message from website https://www.widgetsquad.com/widgets/whatsapp

[image]

Comment: Link only answers to paid software can be mistaken for spam, particularly when the same content is left on multiple questions.